# Newly installed Chamberlain garage door opener blinks lights twice when trying to open

Tags: garage-door-opener

I installed a new Chamberlain B4505T garage door opener.  When I press the open button the lights blink twice and nothing happens.  The sensors seem to be installed correctly.  There is an amber light in one and a green light in the other.  If I block the beam the green light goes out.  Does anyone have any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Is it the actual lights flashing and not the LED's next to the learn button?

Comment: It is the main garage lights flashing. You can hear the relay click on and off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what it was.  I didn't have the up and down limits set. Once I set them everything worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Were they not set by default?

Comment: I don't think they can be set by default because the motor doesn't know what position the trolley is at.

Comment: Every opener I've ever installed has had some existing start and stop position which just needed shifting. I don't recall every encountering a procedure that required setup before the thing would move. Maybe it's a recent thing.

Comment: It might be a safety feature to stop you from folding your door in half if the stop is set too low.

Comment: Had the exact same issue and setting the limits was indeed the fix. Would be a useful addition to the manual's troubleshooting section. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

> Two Flashes: A wire to a sensor is shorted out or a black/white wire is reversed.

https://support.chamberlaingroup.com/s/article/What-does-the-flashing-LED-next-to-the-learn-button-mean-1484145519298

https://www.google.com/search?q=Chamberlain+B4505T+two+blinks

That information is probably also in the installation manual. There's usually a troubleshooting section.